# Access Denied Page with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to code up a small application that uses footlocker and scrapes certain pages from the website. Now the way I want to do the app is by starting at the footlocker homepage and then clicking through different parts on the website. Below I have given an example of one of the additional links that I would click to then scrape. The issue though that I am having is that when the application finds the button and clicks on it I go to a error page kind of and then if I refresh the page I get an Access denied page. If anyone could help me with this issue I would greatly appreciate it. One idea that I thought might be the issue would have to deal with cookies but Im not experienced enough in web based applications to know if that is the case.

```
webpage = r"http://www.footlocker.com/" 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\saleh\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(webpage)
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Sitemap')]")[0].click()
```

Comment: That site has been broken since forever https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/footlocker.com.html

Comment: What is your end goals? What do you want to do?

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel for now im just trying to get better with scrapping web pages and learn how to interact with websites like footlocker to hopefully create applications that can monitor certain products on the page.

Comment: @Martheen That makes no sense because I can access all the pages on chrome but when I use the webdriver.Chrome tab I get access denied errors

Answer (score 0):

Try simulate what a normal browser would do:

### add headers

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

opts = Options()

# Add headers
user_agent =  ('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) '
'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
'Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36')
opts.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')

# Remove the Automation Info 
opts.add_argument('--disable-infobars')

# if you move chromedriver.exe into C:\Windows or C:\Users\saleh or location where this code is executed, then you don’t have to pass it here

chrome_exe = r'C:\Users\saleh\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_exe, chrome_options=opts)
```

URL should not repr `r`

```py
webpage = 'http://www.footlocker.com/'
driver.get(webpage)
```

Observer what you see. Open  Developer Tools, and perform the step manually first while observer the elements you are interacting. Then write code to do the same steps.